# Orientation Change adds margin/padding

Tags: css, responsive-design

singforpleasure.nicktoye.co.uk on the iPhone/mobile device breaks the layout when you go from portrait to landscape to portrait.  When you return to portrait it adds some extra spacing to the right.

Is this a bug?

Comment: have you written any orientation specific styles using css3 media quires for responsive layouts?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Here is my sass generated css - https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6155166

Answer (score 0):

You must adapt the meta viewport to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Then it should be fine.